# Spring @Value field injection in mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

```
@Service
public class MyClass {

...

  @Autowired
  public MyClass(@Value("${my.value}") String myValue)  {
      ...
  }

...
}
```

My Test class:

```
public class MyTest {

    @Mock(name = "solrServer")
    private SolrServer solrServer;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClassMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    ....
}
```

I have an exeption as follow:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  Cannot instantiate
>   @InjectMocks field named 'myClassMock' of type 'class
>   mypackage.MyClass'. You haven't provided the
>   instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
>   However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception
>   : null
>
> at mypackage.MyTest.setUp(MyTest.java:46)
>       ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   ...

How to inject @Value field from MyTest class, and fixed it?

Comment: In code reviews and other discussions I've been trying to dissuade people from using the `@InjectMocks` annotation. Please see [this article](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/) for a very accessible explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it within the `@Before` annotated method by making an instance of your class manually, like so:

```
public class MyTest {

    @Mock(name = "solrServer")
    private SolrServer solrServer;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClassMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        myClassMock = new MyClass("value you need");
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    ....

}
```